# The noun form of the verb "itch" can be either "itch" or "itching", according to all reliable dictionaries. But is there any difference between them?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

The following examples are from the Cambridge online dictionary. Is it possible to use "itching" for the first and "itch" for the second sentence (can we use these two words interchangeably as nouns)?

"I have an itch on the back of my neck."

"The itching is due to an allergic reaction to the mite."

Comment: Since it's a contrast between zero derivation and an active suffix, the suffixed one refers to a repeated or chronic condition, while the zero conversion refers (with _itch_, at least) to an evanescent body twinge, something that will pass, or that will be troubling if it doesn't.

Comment: Not quite. You cannot say *I have an **itching** on the back of my neck*. (However you can say *the **itch** is due to …*) *Itching* is synonymous in function with *scratching*, but *itch* is synonymous in function with *blister*. They mean slightly different things. And if you replace *the itching* with *the itch* (which is grammatical), you change the meaning.